# Require one attribute between choices in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating an angular directive and I want the user to specify a 'type' of the directive.

For example:

```
<my-directive type-a></my-directive>
```

or

```
<my-directive type-b></my-directive>
```

or

```
<my-directive type-c></my-directive>
```

I know I can do:

```
<my-directive type="a"></my-directive>
```

and then require the type attribute but then I'm doing string matching. Is there anyway to do this by requiring one of 'type-a', 'type-b', or 'type-c' to be present?

Comment: String comparison as opposed to what?? Attribute comparison??? You "require" it by making sure that the type is set when the directive is compiled or else you throw an error. What's so hard about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much background info, I came up with this solution.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FB9pS/2/)

So basically `myDirective` has a controller which is shared by type directives (`type-a`, `type-b`.. and so on). The type directive sets the type on the scope of `myDirective`.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.type = '';

            this.setType = function(type){
                if($scope.type === '') $scope.type = type;
                else throw 'type can be only defined once. Current type is '+$scope.type
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.type);
        }
    }
});


myApp.directive('typeA', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^myDirective',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.setType('typeA');
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('typeB', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^myDirective',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.setType('typeB');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do `<div data-my-directive="a"></div>` which is a lot safer for cross-browser and w3c. Then the directive would be something like:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      type: '='
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
    }
  };
});
```